# Animated page style change after swipe

Tags: html, jquery, css, animation, jquery-mobile

I decided to create a page where, after swiping a finger on a mobile device, its css style changes completely.

**I managed to achieve it all. It works as follows:**

1. The first style is specified in the main.css file
2. Each subsequent one (there are four) is specified in other file for convenience
3. I detect the swipe with the help of jQuery Mobile library
4. After swipe, the class changes for the body so you can specify a separate style for each change

Everything works fine, but I would like these swipes to be animated.
I don't know how to do it because it's one side only the styles change.

**Can it be done? And how?**

[Image of the intended effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgEyl.jpg)

The photo shows how I would like the animation to look halfway through its duration.

Thanks in advance for all answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using the window swipe function with jquery

```
window.on("swipe", function() {}
```

When you are changing the classes for the element (or body) you can also specify the animation/transition in css. For example, if you were to change this div here you can specify the animation or transition for the new class that you are adding-

```
<div class = "classOne"></div>
<style>
.classTwo {
   transition: all 2s ease;
   background-color: blue;
  }
  </style>
```

So now when you change the divs class to classTwo with jQuery, the transition or animation will apply.

Comment: My point is that the styles are supposed to slide one after the other. Now they only page elements move.

Comment: You can just use animation delay on the elements :)

Comment: My point is for the styles to move like this: https://codepen.io/anna_blok/pen/eYYRbQY

Comment: I’m sorry, I don’t have an answer for that. Good luck